# Remove Google Play Music from Debian

Tags: debian, delete, music-player, google

I am running a Debian stretch distribution with Cinnamon.

I would like to remove Google Play Music and I don't know how I installed it.

I may have downloaded the .deb package here : https://www.googleplaymusicdesktopplayer.com/
but the command

```
dpkg -r package.deb
```

doesn't work

Moreover I can't list it with

```
dpkg -l | grep google
dpkg -l | grep music
```

According to the attached picture, it is related to google-chrome package, but I don't want to uninstall google-chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the package is "google-play-music-desktop-player" and removing it with `dpkg --remove google-play-music-desktop-player` works just fine. `.deb` is just a file extension and not part of the package name; `dpkg --remove` wants the name of an installed package, not the filename of a package.

`dpkg -l | grep foo` is a very unreliable way of looking for installed packages, especially when you're uncertain about keywords. `apt-cache search` tends to be better at it.

```
shadur@axiom: ~/Downloads/ > sudo dpkg -i google-play-music-desktop-player_4.4.1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package google-play-music-desktop-player.
(Reading database ... 411755 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-play-music-desktop-player_4.4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-play-music-desktop-player (4.4.1-1) ...
Setting up google-play-music-desktop-player (4.4.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...

shadur@axiom: ~/Downloads/ > dpkg -l googl\*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                     Version           Architecture      Description
+++-========================-=================-=================-=====================================================
ii  google-play-music-deskto 4.4.1-1           amd64             An Electron wrapper for Google Play Music

shadur@axiom: ~/Downloads/ > sudo dpkg --remove google-play-music-desktop-player
(Reading database ... 411831 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing google-play-music-desktop-player (4.4.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
shadur@axiom: ~/Downloads/ > 

shadur@axiom: ~/Downloads/ > dpkg -l googl\*
dpkg-query: no packages found matching googl*
```

Comment: This package is not installed:

      sudo dpkg --remove google-play-music-desktop-player
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove google-play-music-desktop-player which isn't installed


But I can launch the player with the menu and it works fine. I can't find the package for this player with apt-get cache or dpkg -l. it seems the player is related to google-chrome

Comment: See edit: It works just fine. Are you sure you still have it installed and you didn't just forget to stop the running process as well?

Comment: It doesn't help. It seems I didn't install it via dpkg and the .deb package.

sudo dpkg -l googl\*
[sudo] password for fernand: 
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  google-chrome- 62.0.3202.94 amd64        The web browser from Google

Comment: If you didn't install it via `dpkg`, then `dpkg` won't be able to help you remove it.

Comment: @Smilia Install the package again using `dpkg` then remove it with `dpkg --remove` . It should work for you.

Comment: Thank you GAD3R.
In fact I removed google-chrome-stable and I reinstalled it and now google-play-music is removed. SO everything is fine ;)

Comment: If it's not too much to ask of whoever downvoted this to leave a comment why they did so?

Answer (score 0):

I was annoyed to discover this application icon on my centos 8 system. Seems my Chrome installation (which uses the sync feature) had the Google Play Music extension installed. I went into Chrome's settings and under Chrome Apps, on the Extensions section, simply removed the Google Play Music extension. This immediately removed the application and icon without me needing to `dnf` remove/reinstall anything.

Seemed strange, I had been using this web browser for months, but until a recent update it had not installed this standalone application.